# Why is my filling calender table procedure skipping dates?

Tags: mysql, while-loop, counter, procedure

Why is my MYSQL procedure skipping dates? I've been looking at it for a while now but can't seem to see the problem.

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS filldates;
    DELIMITER |

    CREATE PROCEDURE filldates(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
    BEGIN
    SET @counterr = 1;
      WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
        SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        IF(@counterr <= 7) THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO kalender (datum,week_id) VALUES (dateStart,1);
        SET @counterr =@counterr+1;
        ELSEIF(@counterr > 7 AND @counterr <= 14) THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO kalender (datum,week_id) VALUES (dateStart,2);
        SET @counterr =@counterr+1;
        ELSE
        SET @counterr = 1;
        END IF;
      END WHILE;
    END
    |
    DELIMITER ;
    CALL FillCalendar('2015-12-31', '2016-03-15');
```

It skips every 15th date. I'm probably missing something

**edit:**
I changed the query by putting an insert in the ELSE statement, but i still get the same result:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS filldates;
    DELIMITER |

    CREATE PROCEDURE filldates(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
    BEGIN
    SET @counterr = 1;
      WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
        SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        IF(@counterr <= 7) THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO kalender (datum,week_id) VALUES (dateStart,1);
        SET @counterr =@counterr+1;
        ELSEIF(@counterr > 7 AND @counterr <= 14) THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO kalender (datum,week_id) VALUES (dateStart,2);
        SET @counterr =@counterr+1;
        ELSE
        INSERT IGNORE INTO kalender (datum,week_id) VALUES (dateStart,3);
        SET @counterr = 1;
        END IF;
      END WHILE;
    END
    |
    DELIMITER ;
    CALL FillCalendar('2015-12-31', '2016-03-15');
```

Comment: When `@counterr` is 15, it'll run through one loop doing nothing but setting `@counterr` to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that the same logic you have defined yourself. Look at your code logic

```
    IF(@counterr <= 7) THEN

    ELSEIF(@counterr > 7 AND @counterr <= 14) THEN

    ELSE        // This is where 15th date is skipped
    SET @counterr = 1;
    END IF;
```

per your edited code you should atleast have 1 record inserted in in 3rd week and then it will skip since you are re-setting counter to 1.

```
    ELSE
    INSERT IGNORE INTO kalender (datum,week_id) VALUES (dateStart,3);
    SET @counterr = 1; //Re-setting the counter to 1 which will skip again
```

Comment: I added an insert in the ELSE statement, but i still get the same result

Comment: @ElFietsbel, per your edited code you should atleast have 1 record inserted in in 3rd week and then it will skip since you are re-setting counter to 1.